# Convert Int to String in Swift and remove optional wrapping?

Tags: swift

I am attempting to convert `Int?` to a String and assign it to a label without including the optional text. I currently have:

```
struct Choice: Mappable{

    var id: String?
    var choice: String?
    var questionId: String?
    var correct: Bool?
    var responses: Int?


    init?(map: Map) {

    }


    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        id  <- map["id"]
        questionId  <- map["questionId"]
        choice <- map["choice"]
        correct <- map["correct"]
        responses <- map["responses"]

    }


}
```

In the class accessing it

```
var a:String? = String(describing: self.currentResult.choices?[0].responses)
        print("\(a!)")
```

and the output is: 
`Optional(1)`

How would I make it just output `1` and remove the optional text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a` is an `Optional`, so you need to unwrap it prior to applying a `String` by `Int` initializer to it. Also, `b` needn't really be an `Optional` in case you e.g. want to supply a default value for it for cases where `a` is `nil`.

```
let a: Int? = 1
let b = a.map(String.init) ?? "" // "" defaultvalue in case 'a' is nil
```

Or, in case the purpose is to assign the possibly existing and possibly `String`-convertable value of `a` onto the `text` property of an `UILabel`, you could assign a successful conversion to the label using optional binding:

```
let a: Int? = 1
if let newLabelText = a.map(String.init) {
    self.label.text = newLabelText
}
```

Comment: If you want to update `self.label.text` only when that expression is not nil, you could do: `self.label.text =  a.map(String.init) ?? self.label.text`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't?

```
let a : Int = 1
var b = "\(a)"
print(b)
```

so

```
$ swift
[ 9> let a : Int = 1
a: Int = 1
[ 10> var b = "\(a)"
b: String = "1"
[ 11> print(b)
1
```

By the way there are other options like this one

```
12> var c = a.description
c: String = "1"
 13> print(c)
1
```

Comment: The Int? is part of a class that data is mapped to during an API request and I need the ? in the instantiation  as part of the ObjectMapper I am using.

Comment: Okay, so you should put the right code snippet here.